# Magento free shipping rule on Custom Option

Tags: magento, fedex

We have 700 simple product and a custom option to every product. we need to apply a rule if someone select custom option then he will get free shipping. otherwise shipping charge will be applied.
Is it possible in Magento ? can anyone please give any solution. how can i apply free shipping on custom option.